# JavaFX + ProcessBuilder / Runtime.exec() starts process after JVM closes

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I'm experiencing a very weird behavior from JavaFX. It is related to [Why are Runtime.getRuntime().exec and ProcessBuilder starting my second jar application after the first one exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930856/why-are-runtime-getruntime-exec-and-processbuilder-starting-my-second-jar-appl) that wasn't exactly answered. The proposed workaround is sadly not applicable to my needs.

The behavior arises when starting a process either through ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec() from a JavaFX application specifically. Here's a test code:

```
package testingfx;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestingFX extends Application {       

   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) {
      StackPane root = new StackPane();
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();

      ProcessBuilder builder; 
      builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "C:\\Program Files\\MPC-HC\\mpc-hc64.exe");
      try {
         builder.start();
      } catch (IOException x) {
         System.err.println(x);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }

}
```

If you happen to have MPC-HC installed on your computer you will see it being executed as soon as the application starts, as expected. However, if I now replace the parameter with `"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe"`, VLC will only execute when the application is **closed**.

I was unable to find any information on why this is happening. The same code in Swing is working as expected, so what give? Ideas are most welcome.

Comment: See if using `builder.inheritIO().start()` instead of `builder.start()` works. If that works, then VLC might be printing things to its output and cannot continue because no one is reading (i.e. emptying) the buffer; I have no idea how exiting the parent process affects situations like that.

Comment: Indeed, it works. Specifically VLC was writing a lot of text in its error stream. I was under the impression that such redirection was not necessary, thank you for your help. (Please do post this as a reply so I can properly validate your answer)

Comment: Related: [Why does process hang if the parent does not consume stdout/stderr in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983372/why-does-process-hang-if-the-parent-does-not-consume-stdout-stderr-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1). Also, note you don't have to use `inheritIO`; you could use threads to read the out/err streams or redirect them to a file.